# how to Populate fields from URL parameter in java Springboot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I need to add support for passing field values to a form via a URL parameter when viewing a form which will be used to populate values into the form when it loads.  should support a JSON formatted value of field names and values.  Example:

https://web/form/view?id=1&data={'fieldname':'value'}

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/form/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewDomainForm(HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("command") FormBean inFormBean) {
    

        Form form = formService.getForm(inFormBean.getId());

        FormInstance formInstance = formInstanceService.createFormInstance(form);

        String formInstanceId = (String) session.getAttribute("formInstanceId");
        if (formInstanceId != null && formInstanceId.length() > 0) {
            formInstanceService.deleteFormInstanceById(formInstanceId);
        }
        formInstanceId = formInstance.getId();
        session.setAttribute("formInstanceId", formInstanceId);

        FormBean formBean = prepareFormBean(form);
        formBean.setEmbed(inFormBean.isEmbed());
        formBean.setFormInstanceId(formInstance.getId());

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("externalBaseUrl", configurationService.getValue("core.external.url.base"));
        model.put("fromTaskList", false);
        model.put("form", formBean);
        model.put("flow", new FlowBean());
        model.put("task", new TaskBean());
        return new ModelAndView("form-viewer", model);
    }
```

I have this method for viewing. what would be the best way to Populate fields from URL parameter?

```
 public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

// this is the value that will populate into the form when it loads.
```

Answer (score 0):

First question, why not use `POST` with the `JSON` in the request body?

If the `JSON` will be large, then you will run in a `URL` limitation problem. And you have to encode your URL with `%` and different delimiters which will make it even less debuggable.

But it is doable.
Let's say that you correctly encoded your URL and the JSON is as a `query param`.
What you could do is receive it and either traverse it and create/populate your form or map it to an object and use that:

```java
public ModelAndView viewDomainForm(... @RequestParam("data") String jsonDataInUrl...) 
{
   // Work with jsonDataInUrl either through parsing it or through transforming it into a java bean.
   ...
}
```

[Here](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) is a URL decoder/encoder in case you need it.